# C# FreeLibrary() ArithmeticException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and a C# WPF Application.
 I am actually trying to load 3 DLLs and then unload them. I have to do this because I cannot add those DLL as a reference to my C# project.
The problem is that I keep getting an ArithmeticException with those DLL. I need all of them, because dll1 needs dll2 and dll3 to run properly.
I have been executed my code step by step, and here is what happend :
My LoadLibrary() do found all the DLLs. Once I get to the FreeLibrary(), there is no error, but at the end of my code (exactly, when going out of MainWindow()) I get an ArithmeticException.

I have already tried putting each of my FreeLibrary() in separated `if` to see if one of them were not executed correctly, without any success.
I have also put each of my FreeLibrary() in a `while` to be sure that the ref count goes to 0, but there I am having another interesting thing : my application get lock on my last Dll. It does the first and second `while` correctly, but get stuck to the last one. I have to manually stop the application, and I am not able to continue my step by step, and there is not a single error or whatever on the stacks of the threads.

Here is my code :

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            string dll1Path = "dll/dll1.dll";
            string dll2Path = "dll/dll2.dll";
            string dll3Path = "dll/dll3.dll";

            IntPtr dll3Link = LoadLibrary(dll3Path);
            IntPtr dll2Link = LoadLibrary(dll2Path);
            IntPtr dll1Link = LoadLibrary(dll1Path);

            if(FreeLibrary(dll3Link) == true && FreeLibrary(dll2Link) == true && FreeLibrary(dll1Link) == true)
                 Console.WriteLine("All DLL have been unloaded");
            else
                 Console.WriteLine("One or more DLL were not unloaded properly");

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message); 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are playing with fire and you got burned.  Jerking a DLL is not in general a safe thing to do, you have no idea what code is running inside the DLL.  First do no harm and let Windows take care of this, the DLL will get unloaded at program termination.

Comment: If I do not use the `FreeLibrary()`, I still get an ArithmeticException.

Comment: Contact the vendor or author of the DLL for support.

Answer (score 0):

At what point do you get the exception?

You can call `File.Exists(dll1Path)` to check if your DLL exists. Maybe threre's your problem

Comment: I used the File.Exists() for every DLL, and it did find all of them. As I said, I get the exception at the end of my code, just after the catch, when I leave the public MainWindow()

Answer (score 0):

You code works just fine, for me.  where is you dll/dll1.dll, are they in your bin/debug?

Comment: As I said to @Tomtom, the `File.Exists()` function find all the DLLs, I don't think it is a problem of path. I am still wondering how you did to make this works... Did you created a WPF Application ? Or another one ?
Shall I put the directory 'dll' in a specific place ? It is actually in my bin\debug

Comment: There is one thing I may have forgot to tell you : dll1.dll needs dll2.dll and dll3.dll to run. Is there any order to free the library ? Do I have to free dll1 as the last one or first one ?

Comment: I would think that you would Free dll1, then dll2, then dll3

Comment: I've tried every order possible, and I still get the ArithmeticException. May this be a problem with the DLL itself ?

Comment: By the way, my DLL is a C++ one, and I do not have access to the .h and .cpp. That's why I have used the `LoadLibrary()` function. But I do not think it's the reason that my `FreeLibrary()` got me this ArithmeticException.